# Unable to parse Ajax Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitch

I am trying the new Twitch API and new to Jquery Ajax. I have successfully completed an Ajax request (for a list of top games) and output it on the console log and inspected the console results to ensure that the results are valid.

However, I am unable to parse the Json successfully into HTML for display:

1) The output shows 'undefined'

2) It is not iterating through the whole Json result set (shows 2 instead of 19 results)

Any advice? Thank you

New Twitch API reference:
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-top-games

```
<script>
  $.ajax('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top',
      {
        headers: {
          "Client-ID":  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( data ) {
            var content = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, element){
                content += 'id: ' + element.id + '<br />';
                content += 'name: ' + element.name + '<br />';
                $('#output').html(content);
            });
        }
      })
      .then(console.log);
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="output"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: `$.each(data, ... ` -> `$.each(data.data, ...`

Comment: you can check your json data here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ if it is correct or not .

Comment: _"shows 2 instead of 19 results"_ - Because `data` in your `success` handler is an object with the properties `data` (the actual games) and `pagination`.

Comment: Rory: Thank you, your answer works!

Comment: Andreas: Yes, I realized it from Rory's answer. Thank you.

Comment: @royy no problem, glad to help. I added it as an answer below, with a more complete explanation of why it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-top-games) you can see that there is a `data` property returned in the response. As such you need to iterate through `data.data`, not just `data`. The first `data` refers to the entire object you receive through the argument to the `success` handler, the second `data` refers to the property within that object.

To save confusion it would be worth renaming the argument in the `success` handler, to `response` for example.

Also note that you're appending the `content` in every iteration of your loop, even though you add more to it in the following iteration. As a result this will duplicate all the previous text nodes. To fix this, move the `html()` call outside of the loop. Try this:

```js
success: function(response) {
  var content = '';
  $.each(response.data, function(index, element) {
    content += 'id: ' + element.id + '<br />';
    content += 'name: ' + element.name + '<br />';
  });
  $('#output').html(content);
}
```

Comment: Rory: Thank you for the explanation and codes! It helped me to better understand Json objects structure and parsing them. I am able to successfully parse and display the information on the website. Ajax, Jquery and Json seems to be a very powerful combination. I have marked this as the acceptance answer.